RabbitMQ One Queue per User/Customer How to deal with consumption
We designed out RabbitMQ model as having one queue per customer.
This way we can guarantee concurrency and FIFO for each of them separately and maximize distribution across our consumers.
However this poses a big question to us, we will have for each consumer, consume from all these queues.
Which for short means, we have to loop through all of our customers, call the channel.consume on their respective queues.
If another customer is added, we will need to add accordingly, maybe do it every one or two minutes, so new queues also getting consumed.
Is this a good idea. Or we will run into consumer side bottlenecks such as long time for setting up consumption or updating these.
Also as the number of customers grows , we have a growing number of consumption plus other supportive queues.
What do you think of our design choice?
We want some feedback on this design of if there is a better way to consume many queues at once. Our idea is similar to sharding, however we are controlling the shards and exactly to which they are going to. The biggest issue is we cannot consume the as one logical queue, which would be perfect to solve this ever increasing number of  queues issue.

I think this approach can work however not sure why you mention that you need to loop through the consumers , you should go for Async Consumer Implementations , where on service start and new consumer addition the appropriate consumer implementation is patched through.  The consumer client should be well designed to match the server.

As there would be many queues lets say
Customer1
Customer2
CustomerN
We would have to fetch from the db the queues that should  exist and consume it.
Thats is our biggest issue, as we are unable to consume for example to all Customer* at once.
So we will have to make this on startup and wherever the customer addition occurs.
And topics do not serve this purpose as in this case we know exactly to which queue publish to.
And we need all queues to persist the data as if consumers go down, or up the messages just continue from where they stopped.

@SoumenMukherjee could you take a look at my response once you have time?!
